onClick not working in a component - Reactjs
I'm making a small React project and in a dropdown, I'm using onClick and calling a function in it.
Here, I'm mapping the data which I get by typing the keywords. For each data, I'm calling a different component called SearchItems.
import React from "react";

const SearchItems = ({ item }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("I'm Clicked");
  };
  return (
    <div className="px-1 hover:bg-green-200 hover:rounded-md w-48">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        {item.name},{" " + item.country}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchItems;

Here onClick is not working, as soon as I click an option nothing logs on the console.

I see no overt issues with the code you have shared here. Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with so readers here could try reproducing any results you are seeing?

Looks like your original posting had the complete [mcve], I don't know why you edited it away.

I thought many people won't be reading the quesiton due to large size, so I just kept it short my bad.

I got the solution for my problem, here I'm calling this component multiple times and this component becomes the option of a dropdown list, so each list item has this button element. If I click any one of it then there is no unique identifier to know which button is clicked. So, if some unique identifier attribute like id is added here then onClick will work as usual.
